# Want to perform date/time value manipulation using struct tm

Tags: c, date, datetime, time

I am receiving a date structure in "24-9-2016 13:30" format. Now I want to convert time value to specific date value, I am doing calculations and have number of hours to add or subtract.

So I don't know:

- how can I initialize tm struct with the date value I have?
- how to add or subtract hours in tc struct variable to get required date?

my intention is
Date received "24-9-2016 13:30" and 5 Hours to add
so final Date: "24-9-2016 18:30"

```
//Temporarily init time to local

time_t tempTime
time(&tempTime);
struct tm *initStruct = localtime(&tempTime);//initialize it with local time
//now modify it to user defined date
initStruct ->tm_year = 2016;
initStruct->tm_mon = 9;
initStruct->tm_hour = 13;
.
.
.
 //Not sure how can I subtract or add hours in this struct to get desired date value
```

This is about formatting user defined not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate UTC offset from IANA timezone name in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845638/how-to-calculate-utc-offset-from-iana-timezone-name-in-c)

Comment: If you want an industrial-strength solution, it is here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone/examples - libicu is the standard way in C to convert times between arbitrary time zones.

Comment: Not really, date is coming from user and need to perform additional steps, main thing is how can I add or subtract from into a struct tm.

Comment: Is the time zone you need the system time zone, or some arbitrary one the user chooses?

Comment: that detailed calculation is in place, which gives how many hours should be added/subtracted in a user given date. I am not sure how to apply those values in struct tm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addition some interval to tm structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214429/addition-some-interval-to-tm-structs)

Comment: Yes, all these are integers, so I can perform addition or subtraction, but it is not handled well in below cases-
if hours are added
Like 4.5 then 13 hours should become 18:30
Or more than 24 then date should modify 

In above cases I will need to add additional code depending on hours value, which is bad, isn't there any system method which will modify entire structure depending on the value assigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm tm = {0};
    if (!strptime("24-9-2016 13:30", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", &tm)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    tm.tm_hour += 5;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(&tm);

    char buf[40];
    if (!strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", &tm)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("result: %s\n", buf);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Points of note:

- We initialize `tm` to all zeroes, then use `strptime` to parse the input string.
- Adding 5 hours is as simple as `tm_hour += 5`.
- We set `tm_isdst` to `-1` to tell `mktime` to figure out automatically whether Daylight Saving Time should be in effect.
- We call `mktime(&tm)` afterwards to normalize the time struct (e.g. adding 5 hours to 23:30 should result in 04:30 (and incrementing the day), not 28:30).
- We convert the result back into human readable form with `strftime`.

A possible issue is that this will output `24-09-2016 18:30`, i.e. it will pad the month/day numbers to 2 places using zeroes. If you don't want that, you'll have to print/format the `tm` fields manually.

Comment: Yes, that is something I want to do. Thanks @melpomene. One thing is, my code is going to run in solaris and i don't think strptime() is available there. Is there any alternative there? or I will have to write my own code for what is done inside strptime?

Comment: @user987316 According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/strptime-3c.html#scrolltoc, `strptime` is available.

Comment: If I have to add hour value such as 4.5, how can I do that? tm_hour is int.

Comment: @user987316 Add 4 to `tm_hour` and 30 to `tm_min`.

Comment: @user987316 Alternative to adding 4 to `tm_hour` and 30 to `tm_min`  1) add 4*60+30 to `tm_min` or 2) add (4*60+30)*60 to `tm_sec`.  `mktime()` will adjust the fields as needed.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene, unfortunately mktime() isn't adjusts seconds values to update minute and hours, not sure if I am doing anything wrong. anyways really Thanks for the extended help.